# Open new tab usin "bulk_actions" prestashop?

Tags: php, tabs, prestashop, bulk

I have another problem in my module in prestashop 1.6, I have a listing where the user can select more than one line in this listing (image 1)[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCAFj.png)

[image]

and when I click on "Select ..." I wanted to open a form in a new tab (Picture 2)[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZfH8.png).

[image]

Can someone help me solve this problem for me? Thank you.

code list:

```
protected function renderListDownload() 
    {
        $table ='contabilidade_fat';

        $this->fields_list = array();
        $this->fields_list['data_mov'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('Data movimento'),
                'type' => 'date',
                'search' => false,
                'orderby' => false,
                'align' => 'center',
        );
        $this->fields_list['data_fatura'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('Data fatura'),
                'type' => 'date',
                'search' => false,
                'orderby' => false,
                'align' => 'center',
            );
        $this->fields_list['data_pagamento'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('Data pagamento'),
                'type' => 'date',
                'search' => false,
                'orderby' => false,
                'align' => 'center',
                'width' => 150,
            );
        $this->fields_list['serie'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('Série'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'search' => true,
                'orderby' => false,
                'align' => 'center',
            );
        $this->fields_list['num_doc'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('N. doc'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'search' => true,
                'orderby' => false,
                'align' => 'center',
            );
        $this->fields_list['nome_cliente'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('Nome faturação'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'search' => true,
                'orderby' => false,
                'align' => 'center',
            );
        $this->fields_list['nome'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('Método de pagamento'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'search' => false,
                'orderby' => false,
                'align' => 'center',
            );
        $this->fields_list['nome_banco'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('Nome banco'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'search' => false,
                'orderby' => false,
                'align' => 'center',
            );
        $this->fields_list['valor'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('Valor movimento'),
                'type' => 'price',
                'search' => true,
                'orderby' => false,
                'align' => 'center',
                'filter_key' => 'm!valor',
            );
        $this->fields_list['valor_total'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('Valor fatura'),
                'type' => 'price',
                'search' => true,
                'orderby' => false,
                'align' => 'center',
            );
        $this->fields_list['valor_pago'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('Valor total'),
                'type' => 'price',
                'search' => true,
                'orderby' => false,
                'align' => 'center',
            );
        $this->fields_list['valor_movimento'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('Valor pagamento'),
                'type' => 'price',
                'search' => true,
                'orderby' => false,
                'align' => 'center',
            );
        $this->fields_list['obs'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('Observações'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'search' => false,
                'orderby' => false,
                'align' => 'Center',

            );
        $this->fields_list['envio_recibo'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('Email recibo'),
                'type' => 'bool',
                'active' => 'envio_recibo',
                'search' => true,
                'orderby' => false,
                'align' => 'center',
                'ajax' => true,
            );
        $ignore = false;
        if (Tools::isSubmit('submitReset'.$table))
        {
            $this->processResetFilters($table);
            $ignore = true;
        }

        $filters = array();
        foreach($this->fields_list as $k => $field)
        {
            if(!$ignore and isset($field['search']) and $field['search'])
            {
                $filter = $value = '';
                //if($field['type'] == 'date' or $field['type'] == 'datetime')
                $filter_key = $table.'Filter_'.str_replace('.', '_', (isset($field['filter_key']) ? $field['filter_key'] : ''));
                $filter_name = $table.'Filter_'.$k;

                if(Tools::getIsset($filter_key))
                {
                    $value = Tools::getValue($filter_key);
                    $filter = $field['filter_key'];
                    if(is_array($value))
                    {
                        foreach($value as $i => $v)
                            if(Tools::getValue('local_'.$filter_key)[$i] == '')
                                $value[$i] = '';
                        $this->context->cookie->__set($filter_key, serialize($value));
                    }
                    else
                        $this->context->cookie->__set($filter_key, $value);
                }
                elseif(Tools::getIsset($filter_name))
                {
                    $value = Tools::getValue($filter_name);
                    $filter = $k;
                    if(is_array($value))
                    {
                        foreach($value as $i => $v)
                            if(Tools::getValue('local_'.$filter_name)[$i] == '')
                                $value[$i] = '';
                        $this->context->cookie->__set($filter_name, serialize($value));
                    }
                    else
                        $this->context->cookie->__set($filter_name, $value);
                }
                elseif(isset($field['filter_key']) and $this->context->cookie->__isset($filter_key))
                {
                    $value = Tools::unSerialize($this->context->cookie->{$filter_key});
                    $filter = $field['filter_key'];
                }
                elseif($this->context->cookie->__isset($filter_name))
                {
                    $value = Tools::unSerialize($this->context->cookie->{$filter_name});
                    $filter = $k;
                }


                //if($k == 'active') var_dump($field['filter_key'], Tools::getValue($this->table.'Filter_'.str_replace('.', '_', $field['filter_key'])), Tools::getValue($this->table.'Filter_'.$k));
                if($filter and $value != '')
                {
                    if($field['type'] == 'date' or $field['type'] == 'datetime')
                    {
                        $filter = str_replace('!', '.', $filter);
                        if($value[0] != '')
                            $filters[] = $filter." >= '".$value[0]."'";
                        if($value[1] != '')
                            $filters[] = $filter." <= '".$value[1]."'";

                        $this->fields_list[$k]['value'] = $value;
                    }
                    elseif(!isset($field['type']) or $field['type'] == 'price')
                    {
                        $filter = str_replace('!', '.', $filter);
                        $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
                        if(strpos($value, '.') == false)
                        {
                            $filters[] = $filter." >= ".$value;
                            $filters[] = $filter." < ".($value + 1);
                        }
                        else
                            $filters[] = $filter." = ".$value;
                    }
                    elseif(!isset($field['type']) or $field['type'] == 'text')
                        $filters[] = $filter." LIKE '%".$value."%'";
                    elseif($field['type'] == 'bool' and isset($field['filter_key']))
                        $filters[] = $field['filter_key']." = ".$value."";
                    else
                    {
                        $filters[] = $filter." = '".$value."'";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // remove from cookie if no value
                    if(isset($field['filter_key']) and $this->context->cookie->__isset($table.'Filter_'.str_replace('.', '_', $field['filter_key'])))
                        $this->context->cookie->__unset($table.'Filter_'.str_replace('.', '_', $field['filter_key']));
                    elseif($this->context->cookie->__isset($table.'Filter_'.$k))
                        $value = $this->context->cookie->__unset($table.'Filter_'.$k);
                }
            }
        }
        //var_dump($_POST,$filters);exit;
        $res = $this->context->cookie->write();

        $id_metodopagamento = Configuration::get('CONTA_meto');
        $id_contabilidade_banco = Configuration::get('CONTA_banco');
        $datei = Configuration::get('CONTA_datei');
        $datef = Configuration::get('CONTA_datef');

        $content = $this->getListDownload($id_metodopagamento, $datei, $datef, $id_contabilidade_banco, $filters);  

        $helper = new HelperList();
        $helper->module = $this;
        $helper->shopLinkType = '';
        $helper->simple_header = false;
        $helper->identifier = 'id_contabilidade_faturacao';
        $helper->actions = array('edit');
        $helper->show_toolbar = true;
        $count = '<span class="badge">'.count($content).'</span>';
        $helper->title = $this->l('List Invoices Download').': '.$count;
        $helper->table = $table;
        $helper->{$helper->table.'_pagination'} = 50;
        $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
        $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;
        $helper->force_show_bulk_actions = true;
        $helper->bulk_actions = array(
            'enviar_email' => array(
                'text' => $this->l('Selecionar para envio email'),
                'icon' => 'icon-send',
                'confirm' => $this->l('Tem a certeza que selecionou corretamente?')
            )
        );

         //var_dump($this->displayAddLink($token = null, $id, $name = null), $this->displayEnvioLink($token = null, $id, $name = null));exit;
        $this->_html .= $helper->generateList($content, $this->fields_list);
    }
```

code bulk_actions:

```
if (Tools::isSubmit('submitBulkenviar_emailcontabilidade_fat'))     
        {
            $res = false;
            if(!empty($_POST["contabilidade_fatBox"]))
            {
                $res = $this->renderFormEmailRecibo();
            }
            else
            {
                $this->_error .= $this->displayError($this->l('Nenhum item selecionado'));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Good morning, does anyone have any information or tips for my question above?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi did you find a solution yet?